# Promiseチェーンの仕様が理解できません

Tags: javascript, 非同期, promise

JavaScriptの非同期処理、Promiseを学習しています。

Promise構文において、thenメソッドの返り値は新しいPromiseインスタンスというところまでは理解できました。しかしその点を知ったことで、かえってわからなくなってしまったことがあります。

```
resolvePromise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
  resolve('成功');
})
resolvePromise
  .then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
    return('成功2'); //★
  })
  .then((val2) => {
    console.log(val2);
  })

　//結果：成功 成功2
```

このPromiseチェーンでは最初のthen（★）でreturnを使い、
次のthenに文字列「成功2」を渡しています。

thenメソッドの返り値は別のPromiseインスタンスですが、
ここでreturnを使うと、返りはPromiseインスタンスではなく、
Strings（'成功2'）になってしまうのではないかと疑問に感じました。

thenの中のreturnは糖衣構文なのでしょうか。
技術書やPromiseについて詳しく解説されているサイトを閲覧しても
触れられていないのですが、この点が腑に落ちません。

どなたかご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thenメソッドの返り値は別のPromiseインスタンスですが、ここでreturnを使うと、返りはPromiseインスタンスではなく、Strings（'成功2'）になってしまうのではないかと疑問に感じました。

前の質問者さんのスレッドで紹介した MDN の記事、

Promise.prototype.then()
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

の「返値」のセクションに、

> 返値
> 新しい Promise をすぐに返します。
> 返されたプロミス（p と呼ぶ）の振る舞いは、ハンドラーの実行結果に依存し、一連の特定のルールに従います。もしハンドラー関数が、
> ・値を返した場合、 p は返値をその値として履行されます。

・・・と書いてある通りではないのでしょうか？

上で言う「ハンドラー」は質問者さんのコードで言うと、

```js
(val) => {
    console.log(val);
    return('成功2'); //★
  }
```

なので、返された Promise は '成功2' をその値として履行と言うことになるはずです。

---

**【追記】**

下のコメント欄で「回答欄に追記します」と書いた件です。

自分も 100% 分かっているわけではないので想像も混じってますが、以下のようなことになっていると思います。

以下の MDN の記事の図を見てください。

Promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

(1) 質問のコードにある resolvePromise が図の左端の Promise に相当

(2) resolve('成功') となっているので Promise は「履行」状態となる

(3) 図の「履行 (fulfill)」の矢印の方向に沿って進む

(4) then は新しい「待機」状態の Promise  (図の左から 2 つ目の Promise) を返す

(5) 図の左端の Promise は「履行」状態なので then(onFulfilled, onRejected) の onFulfilled ハンドラが実行される

(6) 上の (4) の Promise の状態は「履行」になる

(7) 図の右端の then 以降でも、上の (3) から (6) と同様な処理が行われる

以上は「履行」の場合ですが、「拒否」(失敗) の場合は以下のコードで試してみると動きが分かると思います。

```js
// 1つの resolve または reject だけを呼びだす
let resolvePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //resolve('成功');
    reject('失敗');   // resolve があると無視される
});

resolvePromise.then(
    (val) => { console.log(val); return '成功2'; },

    // 以下のようにすると次の then では (val) => { ... } が呼び出される
    //(err) => { console.log(err); return '失敗2'; }

    // 以下のようにすると次の then では (err) => { ... } が呼び出される
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject('失敗2');
        })
    }
).then(
    (val) => { console.log(val); },
    (err) => { alert(err); } // こちらが呼ばれれば alert が出る
);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。returnについて誤解していました。  
return('成功2'); //★部分は、.thenへの戻り値ではなく、thenの内部に定義した関数の戻り値であって、thenに対する戻り値ではない。  
thenは中に書いた関数の戻り値（この場合は"成功2"）を受け取った新しいPromiseとなる仕様。

と理解しましたが、合っていますでしょうか？

Comment: ちょっと違うような気がします。then の戻り値は Promise となる。Promise が成功するとハンドラ関数（質問者さんのコードでは (val)=>{...} ）が呼び出される。ハンドラ関数が値を返す場合（質問者さんのコードでは return('成功2'); ） 、その値が Promise の履行値となる。その履行値が次の then のハンドラ関数の引数 val2 に渡される・・・と言うのが当たっていると思います。

Comment: ちなみに、質問者さんのコードで return('成功2'); が無い場合は、MDN のドキュメントに "何も返さなかった場合、 p は undefined の値で履行されます" と書いてある通り、コンソールには「成功 undefined」と表示されるはずです。お試しください。理解が深まるかも。

Comment: すみません、まだ完全に理解が追い付かなくて。then内部のハンドラー関数が処理されるより前に、まずthenが新しいPromiseとなり、それからハンドラー関数が実行されるという順になる。ということでしょうか。

Comment: その言い方はちょっと違うと思います。上にも書きましたが、then は「新しい Promise をすぐに返します」です。さらに、MDN のドキュメントに「この新しいプロミスは、現在のプロミスの状態に関係なく、返すときには常に待機状態です」と書いてあります。ということで、その時点ではハンドラ関数は動いてません。これも上に書きましたが、「Promise が成功するとハンドラ関数が呼び出される」と言うことになります。

Comment: thenが新しいPromiseを返して「Promise が成功するとハンドラ関数が呼び出される」。
「（新しい）Promiseが成功すると」というところで、ちょっとわからなくなってしまいます。thenによって返された（新しい）Promiseが成功しているかどうかどのように判定されるのでしょうか？

MDNドキュメントにも目を通してはいますが、どうしてもまだモヤモヤが残ってしまいます。

もしよろしければ後少しだけお付き合いいただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 上のコメントの私の説明は適切ではなかったかもしれません。回答欄に追記します。

Comment: 拝見させていただきました。だんだん頭の中が整理されてきました。「(5) onFulfilled ハンドラが実行される」で図の中央上の「非同期処理」が完了すると、左から 2 つ目の Promiseの状態が待機→履行になる。と理解しましたが、WebSurfer様の見解と相違あればお伝えください。

Comment: そうです。最初の質問とは違ってきてますし、一つの回答が次の疑問を呼んで、質問を繰り返されてはキリが無いです。もう終わりにしましょう。

Comment: 理解が進みましたがまだまだ勉強が必要そうです。がんばります。長々とありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

[Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) より

> `then()` は [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) オブジェクトのメソッドであり、最大 2 つの引数として、 `Promise` が成功した場合と失敗した場合のコールバック関数を取ります。これは直ちに同等の `Promise` オブジェクトを返し、プロミスの他のメソッドを[連鎖](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining)呼び出し

(文章が途中で切れてる気がするけど, 原文ママ)

`.then()` メソッドから, 何らかの値を返す関数を受け取り 呼び出しても
その値を 別の関数から直接参照したりすることはありません
記されてる通り, **`Promise` オブジェクトを返し**ます

元の Promiseオブジェクトが値を受け取り, 新しい Promiseオブジェクトを作り出す
チェーンに沿って実行されるだけ

[Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) より

> `Promise.resolve()` は、ネイティブの `Promise` のインスタンスを特別扱いしています。 `value` が `Promise` またはそのサブクラスに属し、 `value.constructor === Promise` の場合、新しい `Promise` インスタンスを作成せずに、`Promise.resolve()` で直接 `value` を返すことができます。そうでない場合、`Promise.resolve()` は基本的に `new Promise((resolve) => resolve(value))` の一括指定となります。

(`Promise.resolve()` 内部で使用してるはず)

参考:

- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Promise() コンストラクター](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) の「典型的な流れ」辺り